# Connectionstring from web.config-Crystal Reports

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, crystal-reports, connection-string

I am having the following function to create crystal report. I want to change my function so that it uses the connection info from the web.config

```
MyRepository _MyRepository = new MyRepository();            
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection myConnection = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection();
myConnection.ConnectionString = "Data Source=MySRV;Initial Catalog=mydb;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=sa;Password=mypass";
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand MyCommand = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand("dbo.spMySP");
MyCommand.Connection = myConnection;
MyCommand.Parameters.Add("@PositionID", SqlDbType.Int).Value = (cmbPositions.SelectedValue == "" ? 0 : Convert.ToInt32(cmbPositions.SelectedValue));
MyCommand.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter MyDA = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter();
MyDA.SelectCommand = MyCommand;
ASale _DS = new ASale();
MyDA.Fill(_DS, "dbo.spMySP");
rptSale oRpt = new rptSale();
oRpt.SetDatabaseLogon("sa", "mypass");
oRpt.SetDataSource(_DS);
oRpt.SetParameterValue(0, "param1");
oRpt.SetParameterValue(1, "param2");
oRpt.SetParameterValue(2, "param3" );
oRpt.SetParameterValue(3, (cmbPositions.SelectedValue == "" ? 0 : Convert.ToInt32(cmbPositions.SelectedValue)));
CrystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = oRpt;
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
myConnection.ConnectionString = ConfigurationManager
    .ConnectionStrings["ConStrName"]
    .ConnectionString;
```

Comment: Now when crystal report viewer is asking me about database credential. I am using oledb ado connection in crystal report in dev. Can U please guide